# How to do a counter on time range queries in a MongoDB database with Pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb

I am trying to query my MongoDB database with a python script with a counter on a time range. I know there is some differences when translating, for instance adding " " around the key-words. Yet I think I don't know all the rules necessary to do such queries fom python.

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import pymongo
import datetime
import pprint
import dateutil.parser

from pymongo import MongoClient


client = MongoClient('mongodb://HIDDEN')

dateStr="2017-05-22T00:00:00.780+0000"
myDateTime =dateutil.parser.parse(dateStr)

db = client['swiper']
cursor = db.multifeeds.aggregate(
    [
        {"$match": { "action": 2, "$and": [ { "date": { "$gte": myDateTime, "$lte": myDateTime } } ] }},
        {"$unwind": {"path" : "$pagesSeen"}},
        {"$match": {"pageSwiped": "SMART"}},
        {"$count": "count"},
    ]
)

for document in cursor:
    print (document)
```

On studio 3T, I have no issue getting the results :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDZt9.png)

But on the terminal I get nothing at all, like always when he is not happy about my 3T/MongoDB queries...

The desired output is only an integer:

```
Out[22]: 
       125
```

Do you have any ideas ?

I inpired myself from : http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html#querying-by-objectid

Actually I would have loved to use a parameter `d` for the date or several for day, month, year.

Comment: @S.M.Styvane, I saw your response and your suggestion and updated my question to show its difference.

Comment: Remove `NumberInt` and use integer

Comment: @S.M.Styvane It remains the same : no output...

Comment: @S.M.Styvane can you reopen my question as far as it is about time queries no more but about the structure of queries with pymongo ?

Comment: I am willing to reopen your question but before I do that, show us sample document with the expected output. Also don't use an image.

Comment: @S.M.Styvane Understood, I've updated. I only desire an integer as a result.

Comment: Where is the JSON document? I can't see it in the question.